# Increase ID by one

Tags: c#

I would like to increase variable ID by one after each add, but I'm not really sure how to.

As in now, the ID is always 0 after adding to a listbox.

```
   public class  Animal
    {
        private string name;
        private int age;
        private string gender;
        private int id; //<-- this is the one I want to increase.

      public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set
            {
                if (value > 0)
                    id = value;
            }
}
```

Here is my animal manager class that handles the logic. I tried creating a animal object and increase the id, but it didn't work.

```
class AnimalManager
    {
        private List<Animal> AnimalList;
        private Animal ani;

        public AnimalManager()
        {
            AnimalList = new List<Animal>();
            ani = new Animal();
        } 

        public void add(Animal ObjIn)
        {

            AnimalList.Add(ObjIn);
            ani.Id++;

        }
```

Here is how I add to the list.

```
 private void UpdateResults()
        {
            Resultlst.Items.Clear();  //Erase current list
            //Get one elemnet at a time from manager, and call its 
            //ToString method for info - send to listbox
            for (int index = 0; index < animalmgr.ElementCount; index++)
            {
                Animal animal = animalmgr.GetElementAtPosition(index);


               toString method.
               Resultlst.Items.Add(animal.ToString());

            }
        }
```

Comment: Try making id static and just increase the id in the constructor. Then you dont have to do it manually.

Comment: I tried it, and it did increase all objects in the listbox by one. What I want to do it is to increase only the new added object.

Comment: How do you know it's not increasing then? I don't see where you check what the id is?

Comment: Try this

Animal.Id = Resultlist.Items.Count
Resultlst.Items.Add(animal.ToString());

Comment: I run the application and add Animals to the list. The first object created has Id 1 the next has object created has id 2 and the previous one also has two. The next one has three but all the previous also gets id 3. It changes the id for all the object created.

Comment: You're never actually changing the ID of any of the animals in the list....you're only incrementing the value of `ani.Id`

Comment: @Kaz Yeah I realized that now.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you keep increasing the ID on an instance of `Animal`... an instance that has nothing to do with the other instances that you're actually adding to the collection.

Replace the private `Animal` instance in your `AnimalManager` with a counter. Increase the counter and assign the new value to the `Animal` instance right before you add it to the collection.

```
private class AnimalManager
{
    private List<Animal> AnimalList;
    private int animalCounter;

    public AnimalManager()
    {
        AnimalList = new List<Animal>();
    }

    public void add(Animal animal)
    {
        animal.Id = animalCounter++;
        AnimalList.Add(animal);
    }
}
```

Comment: I though of that. But I'm not sure how to assign the new value to the Animal instance. I'm separating the `Animal Manager` (in which handles the logic) from the Mainform. `animal` does not exist in `Animal Manager` class.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I see what you mean now. A million thanks to you, sir!